# How to Reconfigure BizTalk User and Group Security Settings manually

Tags: sql, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

How to reconfigure BizTalk User and Group Settings manually without Deleting Databases and biztalk unconfigure features ?

Example -->

Existing BizTalk Server Runtime features :

[image: Original BT Server runtime configuration feature.png]

Need to modify BizTalk Server Runtime features:

[image: Need to modify BT Server runtime configuration feature.png]

Is there any idea or suggestion to add new windows group user on existing BizTalk configuration ?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33650.biztalk-how-to-manually-reconfigure-user-and-group-security-settings-without-deleting-databases.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cfa63246-ba7b-42a7-9e2d-837fc4fe448a/how-do-we-change-the-windows-biztalk-administrators-group-and-biztalk-operators-group-used-to?forum=biztalkgeneral), maybe this help you. The idea is create manually the logins on SQL Server and then modify the users on BizTalk Services.